# jQuery target different window/popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, target

I have jQuery open a popup:

```
function idealPopUp(str){
    var url = str;
    var windowName = "idealPopUp";
    var windowSize = 'height=820,width=784,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes';              
    window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

can I, from the original window, have jQuery target that popup? I want to know when it closes. The content of the popup is from another site and I have no control over it's jas/html etc.

I have this in the original window to try and talk to the popup:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#idealPopUp').unload( function () {
        alert("BING");
    });
});
```

..

..

UPDATED FUNCTION:

```
function idealPopUp(url){
    var windowName = "idealPopUpWindow";
    var windowSize = 'height=820,width=704,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes';

    var idealPopUpWindow = window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);

    $(idealPopUpWindow).unload( function () {
        alert("BING");
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var otherWindow = window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);
```

is a window reference; now you can

```
$(otherWindow).unload(...);
```

Comment: Ok. I understood that. However, I don't understand why the popup opens when I load the page. The function is executed by a button from flash and that's not possible when opening the page. In the popup the url is "function (selector, context) {    return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context, rootjQuery);}"

Comment: My apologies. The name of the function and the name of the variable I gave the window were identical. So, on load when the document was ready, it looked for the instance which in this case was the function and fired that function.

Comment: It's kinda working, however, the unload function triggers as soon as the popup is opened, not when it is closed :/ I will paste an updated version of my function above in the question.