# jQuery window/popup function executing too early

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I'm sorry for posting a "semi-duplicate", but I've stopped getting answers in another question because it seems answered.

Question related to: [jQuery target different window/popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521728/jquery-target-different-window-popup).

So, i have this function which when fired creates a new window/popup. The problem is that jQuery is supposed to be listening for when the new popup is closed and do an alert, but the alert is fire as soon as the popup is created.

the code:

```
function idealPopUp(url){
    var windowName = "idealPopUpWindow";
    var windowSize = 'height=820,width=704,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes';

    var idealPopUpWindow = window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);

    $(idealPopUpWindow).unload( function () {
        alert("BING");
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the event after the page has loaded:

```
function idealPopUp(url){
    var windowName = "idealPopUpWindow";
    var windowSize = 'height=820,width=704,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes';

    // Wrap new window object in a jQuery object
    var $idealPopUpWindow = $(window.open(url, windowName, windowSize));

    $idealPopUpWindow.load( function () {     //  Execute this function on load
        $idealPopUpWindow.unload(function(){  // Bind the actual event
            alert("BING");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Popup is opening but nothing happening on close.

Comment: I've successfully tested this code with jQuery 1.6.3 + FF 8.0.1, and failed to get the code work using jQuery 1.5.2. What jQuery version, browser vendor and URL are you loading?

Comment: src="/js/jquery-1.6.2.js" ... Thank you, anyways. I will tell the dev team about this. Maybe if they upgrade to 1.6.3 it will work.

Comment: The code also works fine for jQuery 1.6.2: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5EsL/1/. Make sure that you're not opening URLs from another origin (domain), because the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/Same_Origin_Policy) prevents [the window from being modified](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5EsL/2/) by an external page.